# Small TaskQueue shared on two computers

Tags: network-interface, software-rec, slurm, gridengine

There are two computers with 12 physical cores each.

Computer A should accept jobs and distribute them among A and B

I want to setup Computers A and B such that

- A will accept jobs (via ssh) and distribute them among A and B (more or less intelligently)
- if possible I'd like to block 4 cores on each computer as "personal requiremets"

Jobs are expected to be either python scripts or executables written in c++ (can involve mpi code).

I have read of slurm and the Sun Grid Engine but that seems a bit too powerful/complicated for this use case (I don't want to spend a week reading how to do it and troubleshooting). Is there an easier solution that satisfies the requirements?

Comment: if A can compute tasks to B, then B is the server, and A is the client, not the other way around.

Comment: Should I have chosen master(A)/slave(A+B) or host(A)/recipient(A+B) instead?

Comment: I'd say A is a client and A and B are compute nodes. But doesn't really matter. Can you tell us a bit about what "a job" is?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have updated the post accordingly and hopefully answered your question :)

Comment: Thanks! Do your machines have a shared piece of storage, or how do you plan on getting results of the jobs back?

Comment: @MarcusMüller that is up to me. Currently there is only A. Machine B will be available in a couple months. I have basically no idea how to set it up, so I can not answer this any better

Comment: maybe we need to talk more deeply what your python tasks are, what kind and amount of data you need, and so on.

Comment: You'd be building a 2-node cluster.  Slurm or similar cluster admin tool (e.g. pbs / torque) are what you need - one of the machines, i.e. computer "A", would need to be both the slurm controller node AND a compute node.  The other, computer "B", only needs to be a compute node.  You also need some form of shared storage between the two machines so that jobs and data can be shared between them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is mainly thought as a shared work station for different people who want to run scripts that last a couple hours/days. MPI programs are likely to be seldom run, but I want to keep the option available. They will mainly perform mathematical tasks like solving PDEs.